# Does Haskell support unbound variables?

Tags: haskell, oz

Does [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) support the concept of [*unbound variables*](http://strasheela.sourceforge.net/strasheela/doc/01-Basics.html#sec20) as in the [Oz programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oz_%28programming_language%29)?

Answer (score 4):

Haskell only supports *variables* in terms of values in (monadic) contexts. Once you look at those,  there are certain ones like `MVar` which can indeed be empty.

If you want to represent simple nullability of a value, though, `Maybe a` is a perfect way to do that, separate from the actual value being a reference to something mutable or just an immutable something.

---

To expand and illustrate:

```
newIORef :: a -> IO (IORef a)
```

But we can easily write `newEmptyIORef` as such:

```
newEmptyIORef :: IO (IORef (Maybe a))
newEmptyIORef = newIORef Nothing
```

Take note that `Maybe (IORef a) ≠ IORef (Maybe a)`.

Comment: Can a Haskell program bind an `MVar` to a value (assign a value to the variable) after it the program declares the variable?  I call this *lazy binding* or *lazy assignment* (or *deferred* binding or assignment).

Comment: @DerekMahar This is kind of the point of MVars, but i am not sure if that was a good example

Comment: @DerekMahar No. There is no way to initialize/declare a variable without defining it.

Comment: The code example given here does not actually use `MVar`s (although if you're only using one thread I guess it's equivalent)